# Auto role in discord.py

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

I checked all codes what I can find but they don't work with my bot.What am I doing wrong?
They’re not much different and they all work, but not in my code. No mistakes in the cmd.
my friend can’t do it either. Bot has administrator privileges (I checked)
role = "NEWS"

```
@bot.event
async def on_member_join(member): 
    rank = discord.utils.get(member.guild.roles, name=role) 
    await member.add_roles(rank)
    print(f"{member} was given the {rank} role.")
```

Second

```
@bot.event
async def on_member_join( member ):
    role = discord.utils.get( member.guild.roles, id = 889869064997068810)
    await member.add_roles( role )
```

Third

```
@bot.event
async def on_member_join(member):
    role = discord.utils.get(member.guild.roles, name='Unverified')
    await member.add_roles(role)
```

All code without this auto role

```
import random
import json
import discord
import datetime
from lol import an
from zdar import answer_hello
from zdar import hello_words
from zdar import maternie
from zdar import answer_maternie
from discord.ext import commands
from config0 import settings 


bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix= settings['prefix'])
bot.remove_command('help')


@bot.command()
async def clear(ctx, amount = 100):
    await ctx.channel.purge( limit = amount )
@bot.command() 
async def hello(ctx):
    await ctx.send(f',{ctx.message.author.mention}!')


@bot.command()
async def cat(ctx):
    await ctx.send(random.choice(an))

@bot.command()
async def time (ctx):
    emb = discord.Embed(title = 'Титульник', colour = discord.Color.green(), url = 'https://www.timeserver.ru/cities/by/minsk')
    emb.set_author(name = bot.user.name, icon_url = bot.user.avatar_url)
    emb.set_footer ( text = ctx.author.name, icon_url= ctx.author.avatar_url)
    emb.set_image( url= 'https://i.pinimg.com/originals/3f/82/40/3f8240fa1d16d0de6d4e7510b43b37ba.gif')
    emb.set_thumbnail( url= 'https://static.wikia.nocookie.net/anime-characters-fight/images/9/90/Eugo_La_Raviaz_mg_main.png/revision/latest/scale-to-width-down/700?cb=20201114130423&path-prefix=ru')
    now_date = datetime.datetime.now()
    emb.add_field( name = 'Time', value='Time:{}'.format( now_date))

    await ctx.send(embed = emb)

bot.run(settings['token'])
```

Comment: Have you tried to set a prefix and not retrieve it from `settings`?

Comment: I tried, but I’ll double-check it.

Comment: it's not working @Dominik

Comment: Is this just about the event or also the commands? You need to enable Intents in the Developer Portal and add some code. Check out the following from the docs: https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/intents.html (You need the `members` Intent)

Comment: @Dominik the bot has admin privileges.

Comment: I used  intents but without ✔️

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to specify the [member intent](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html#discord.Intents.members) to receive `on_member_join` events. You can do this while creating your bot object by adding an intent option:

```
intents = discord.Intents.default()
intents.members = True

bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix=settings['prefix'], intents=intents)
```

**Note**

If your bot is verified you require the `SERVER MEMBERS INTENT` which you can request on the bot page of your application.